# how to change datepicker holotheme day view in android

Tags: android, android-widget, android-datepicker

How can I change this days view to normal? I mean to display days not in a month view calendar, but in a form like months and years?

```
 <DatePicker
            android:id="@+id/datePicker"
            android:layout_width="312dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />
```

[image: holotheme]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to hide the calendar view but still display the day/month/year selector. To achieve that, change your XML to the following:

```
<DatePicker
    android:id="@+id/datePicker"
    android:layout_width="312dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:calendarViewShown="false" />
```